# jQuery: How do I make the selectall work for checkboxes

Tags: javascript, qjson

I have the following code which returns the values for checkboxes
How do  I select/unselect all and get all the selected values?

```
 <p><label><input type="checkbox" id="checkAll"/> Check all</label></p>
<div id="checkboxlist">
    <div><input type="checkbox" value="1" class="chk"> Value 1</div>
    <div><input type="checkbox" value="2" class="chk"> Value 2</div>
    <div><input type="checkbox" value="3" class="chk"> Value 3</div>
    <div><input type="checkbox" value="4" class="chk"> Value 4</div>
    <div><input type="checkbox" value="5" class="chk"> Value 5</div>
    <div>
         <input type="button" value="Get Value" id="buttonClass"> 

    </div>
</div>
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    /* Get the checkboxes values based on the class attached to each check box */
    $("#buttonClass").click(function() {
        getValueUsingClass();
    });

    /* Get the checkboxes values based on the parent div id */
    $("#buttonParent").click(function() {
        getValueUsingParentTag();
    });
});




    function getValueUsingClass(){
        /* declare an checkbox array */
        var chkArray = [];

        /* look for all checkboes that have a class 'chk' attached to it and check if it was checked */
        $(".chk:checked").each(function() {
            chkArray.push($(this).val());
        });

        /* we join the array separated by the comma */
        var selected;
        selected = chkArray.join(',') + ",";

        /* check if there is selected checkboxes, by default the length is 1 as it contains one single comma */
        if(selected.length > 1){
            alert("You have selected " + selected); 
        }else{
            alert("Please at least one of the checkbox");   
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('#buttonClass').on('click', function() {
 var selVals = [];
  $('#checkboxlist input[type=checkbox]:checked').each(function() {
   selVals.push($(this).val());
  });
  
  alert("You selected " + selVals);
});

$('#checkAll').on('click', function(){
 $('#checkboxlist input[type=checkbox]').prop('checked', $(this).prop('checked'));
});

$('#checkboxlist input[type=checkbox]').on('change', function(){
 var allChecked = true;
  $('#checkboxlist input[type=checkbox]').each(function(){
   if(!$(this).prop('checked')){
     allChecked = false;
      return false;
    }
  });
  $('#checkAll').prop('checked', allChecked);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox" id="checkAll" /> Check all</label>
</p>
<div id="checkboxlist">
  <div>
    <input type="checkbox" value="1" class="chk"> Value 1</div>
  <div>
    <input type="checkbox" value="2" class="chk"> Value 2</div>
  <div>
    <input type="checkbox" value="3" class="chk"> Value 3</div>
  <div>
    <input type="checkbox" value="4" class="chk"> Value 4</div>
  <div>
    <input type="checkbox" value="5" class="chk"> Value 5</div>
  <div>
    <input type="button" value="Get Value" id="buttonClass">

  </div>
</div>
```

DEMO: https://jsfiddle.net/zf2obcLd/2/

There are 3 parts, one for getting the checked values:

```
$('#buttonClass').on('click', function() {
    var selVals = [];
  $('#checkboxlist input[type=checkbox]:checked').each(function() {
    selVals.push($(this).val());
  });

  alert("You selected " + selVals);
});
```

On click we loop through all the checked checkboxes `input[type=checkbox]:checked` then we add the value to an array.

The second part is for check all, we change all the checkboxes to match the property `checked` of the check all box.

```
$('#checkAll').on('click', function(){
    $('#checkboxlist input[type=checkbox]').prop('checked', $(this).prop('checked'));
});
```

the third is how you check the "check all" button if they were all manually checked, and un-check it if at least one of them gets unchecked

```
$('#checkboxlist input[type=checkbox]').on('change', function(){
    var allChecked = true;
  $('#checkboxlist input[type=checkbox]').each(function(){
    if(!$(this).prop('checked')){
        allChecked = false;
      return false;
    }
  });
  $('#checkAll').prop('checked', allChecked);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the value of all selected checkboxes you can do it like this:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
        $('#buttonClass').click(function(){
            var checkedValues = $('input:checkbox:checked').map(function() {
                          return this.value;
            }).get();

            console.log(checkedValues);
        });
  
  
       $('#checkAll').click(function(){
            $(".chk").prop('checked', $(this).prop('checked'));
        });
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p><label><input type="checkbox" id="checkAll"/> Check all</label></p>
<div id="checkboxlist">
    <div><input type="checkbox" value="1" class="chk"> Value 1</div>
    <div><input type="checkbox" value="2" class="chk"> Value 2</div>
    <div><input type="checkbox" value="3" class="chk"> Value 3</div>
    <div><input type="checkbox" value="4" class="chk"> Value 4</div>
    <div><input type="checkbox" value="5" class="chk"> Value 5</div>
    <div>
         <input type="button" value="Get Value" id="buttonClass"> 
       
    </div>
</div>
```